# Qt 4.8 Signals/Slots not called after moveToThread()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a class derived from `QObject`, `UploadWorker`, that has been started using the recommended way of running tasks in threads as demonstrated in the Qt documentation.

```
QThread*      thread = new QThread();
UploadWorker* worker = new UploadWorker();

worker->moveToThread(thread);

connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(doWork()));
```

Now, that works perfectly fine. My `UploadWorker` then tries to start a worker for himself, named `Uploader`, using the same technique.

Here are the necessary parts of the headers.

```
class UploadWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // stuff

public slots:
    void doWork();

signals:
    void allWorkDone();

protected:
    void startUploader();
};

class Uploader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // stuff

public slots:
    void doWork();
    void finishWhenQueueIsEmpty();
};
```

This is the implementation of `UploadWorker`.

```
void
UploadWorker::doWork()
{
    // This method is called when QThread emits started()

    // Prepare the upload thread
    startUploader();

    // Do some important work...

    // Notify the upload thread that we're done
    emit allWorkDone();
}

void
UploadWorker::startUploader()
{
    QThread*  thread = new QThread();
    Uploader* uploader = new Uploader();

    uploader->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(this,     SIGNAL(stopped()),   uploader, SLOT(stop()));
    connect(uploader, SIGNAL(finished()),  thread,   SLOT(quit()));
    connect(thread,   SIGNAL(finished()),  thread,   SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(uploader, SIGNAL(finished()),  uploader, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread,   SIGNAL(started()),   uploader, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(this,     SIGNAL(allWorkDone()), 
            uploader, SLOT(finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()));

    thread->start();
}
```

My problem now is, that the `Uploader::finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()` slot is never triggered. Unless: I remove `uploader->moveToThread(thread);`.

Where's the bug?

*edit*
I forgot to mention that the `Uploader::doWork()` method is called when the thread starts. It's any other slot, in this example `finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()` that don't work.

I fixed a typo regarding the name of the slots.

Comment: So you confirm that with the `moveToThread()` the slot is never triggered, but with, it is?

Comment: is doWork still busy?

Comment: @ratchetfreak which `doWork` do you mean, there are two? @JBL if I don't move `uploader`to `thread` then the slot is triggered, yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One very probable possibility is that you're executing  your `Uploader::doWork()` slot and wait for a call to the slot `Uploader::finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()` to finish its execution, through some synchronization mechanism (a boolean `isRunning` for example).

What you need to do then is connecting your slot like the following:

```
connect(this,     SIGNAL(allWorkDone()), 
        uploader, SLOT(finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()),
        Qt::DirectConnection);
```

and in `finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()` protect the synchro mechanism with a mutex.

Why?

Because the default mode for connection that are made between objects that are in different thread is `Qt::QueuedConnection`. What it does here is that every slot of the `Uploader` class here are queued for execution, that is, the next slot in the queue will run once the thread returns to the event loop (i.e. once the current slot has finished running). Then, it means that in this mode, calling `Uploader::doWork()` and then `Uploader::finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()` will result in the program being stuck in `doWork()`.

With the `Qt::DirectConnection`, the slot will be run in the thread that runs `UploaderWorker::doWork()` and can actually be run while `Uploader::doWork()` is running. 
But then you have two threads that can access the same `Uploader` object and thus you need to protect every access/write to parts of this object.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't think about blocking the event-loop with this construct. Of course, `Qt::DirectConnection` makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @JBL, as we suspected, part of the code that was not posted. Well deduced.

Comment: This was helluva stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
void
UploadWorker::doWork()
{
    // This method is called when QThread emits started()

    // Prepare the upload thread
    startUploader();

    // Do some important work...

    // Notify the upload thread that we're done
    emit allWorkDone();
}
```

the structure here is telling me that you don't let the event loop run until you are actually done with the "important work", this means that no slots will be triggered.

either let the events run by calling `QApplication::processEvents();` periodically or redesign that work so it is processed by a sequence of calls from the event loop.

Comment: Wouldn't the signal allWorkDone() be queued, then doWork would exit, which would then allow the event loop to run and process the signal?

Comment: Your answer is almost as correct as the one by JBL. It certainly helped me understand my bug. Thank you!

Comment: This answer was the solution for me, as the slot that was never called was in a QThread. Changing the connection type didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Uploader class you label the slot: void finishedWhenQueueIsEmpty();

Then you call:-

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(allWorkDone()), uploader, SLOT(finishWhenQueueIsEmpty()));
```

So one is 'finishWhen...' and the other 'finishedWhen..'

If you use this connect syntax (pre Qt 5.0) then you can either check the return value from the connect call, or at least look at the debug output when running in a debugger, which will have told you that the slot was invalid.

With Qt 5 connect syntax, this can be caught at compile time:-

```
connect(this, &UploadWorker::allWorkDone() uploader, &Uploader::finishWhenQueueIsEmpty());
```

Comment: @JBL The connect call references the uploader object with 'finish..', but the Uploader class declares 'finished...' There is not such signal or slot in the posted UploadWorker class. What am I missing?

Comment: I see both UploadWorker and Uploader class declaration. I agree with Merlin069.

Comment: @JBL, the Uploader class declaration is declared in the code posted, right after the UploadWorker class declaration.

Comment: Oh sorry, indeed, there was both. But then that's strange that OP reports that just removing the moveToThread makes it work. (Maybe the code posted isn't up to date with the one he's using...)

Comment: @JBL I'm guessing that the issue of moveToThread may not be part of the posted code, but the wrong naming of the signal in the connect still remains.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I fixed the typo. The signal and slots are correctly named and connected. I suspected something similar, but there are no warnings by Qt.